# Countdown timer stops when switching tabs

Tags: javascript

So basically when I switch tabs, the countdown timer on a specific page just stops counting down and resumes when you return to the tab. Is there anyway to mitigate that so that it counts in the background or it accounts for the time you spend on another tab?

This is basically what I have for js:

```
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
  05 + ":" + 01;
startTimer();


function startTimer() {
  var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
  var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
  var m = timeArray[0];
  var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
  if(s==59){m=m-1}
  if(m<0){
    return
  } else if (m == 0 && s == 0) {
    location.reload();
  }
  
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
    m + ":" + s;
  setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
  
}

function checkSecond(sec) {
  if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {sec = "0" + sec};
  if (sec < 0) {sec = "59"};
  return sec;
}
```

Any ideas whether the time could be done server side or something so that it can't be modified client side? If not, then whatever, but mainly just want to figure out how to make the countdown still work (or account for the time spent) when on another tab.

Comment: Switching tabs never stops the running JS. I checked the code on Chrome browser and countdown timer works fine even when on other tab. What makes you think its not working?

Answer (score 1):

We can store the variable **m** and **s** values either globally or use the local storage to set the values after setting the inner HTML and get the stored values back whenever tabs were switched as:

**Set values:**

`window.localStorage.setItem('minutes', m.toString()); //same for the seconds`

**Get values:**

`window.localStorage.getItem('minutes'); //same for the seconds`

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: But how does it solves the time count issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple solution:
Add this piece of code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var $momentum;

      function createWorker() {
        var containerFunction = function() {
          var idMap = {};

          self.onmessage = function(e) {
            if (e.data.type === 'setInterval') {
              idMap[e.data.id] = setInterval(function() {
                self.postMessage({
                  type: 'fire',
                  id: e.data.id
                });
              }, e.data.delay);
            } else if (e.data.type === 'clearInterval') {
              clearInterval(idMap[e.data.id]);
              delete idMap[e.data.id];
            } else if (e.data.type === 'setTimeout') {
              idMap[e.data.id] = setTimeout(function() {
                self.postMessage({
                  type: 'fire',
                  id: e.data.id
                });
                // remove reference to this timeout after is finished
                delete idMap[e.data.id];
              }, e.data.delay);
            } else if (e.data.type === 'clearCallback') {
              clearTimeout(idMap[e.data.id]);
              delete idMap[e.data.id];
            }
          };
        };

        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
          '(',
          containerFunction.toString(),
          ')();'
        ], {
          type: 'application/javascript'
        })));
      }

      $momentum = {
        worker: createWorker(),
        idToCallback: {},
        currentId: 0
      };

      function generateId() {
        return $momentum.currentId++;
      }

      function patchedSetInterval(callback, delay) {
        var intervalId = generateId();

        $momentum.idToCallback[intervalId] = callback;
        $momentum.worker.postMessage({
          type: 'setInterval',
          delay: delay,
          id: intervalId
        });
        return intervalId;
      }

      function patchedClearInterval(intervalId) {
        $momentum.worker.postMessage({
          type: 'clearInterval',
          id: intervalId
        });

        delete $momentum.idToCallback[intervalId];
      }

      function patchedSetTimeout(callback, delay) {
        var intervalId = generateId();

        $momentum.idToCallback[intervalId] = function() {
          callback();
          delete $momentum.idToCallback[intervalId];
        };

        $momentum.worker.postMessage({
          type: 'setTimeout',
          delay: delay,
          id: intervalId
        });
        return intervalId;
      }

      function patchedClearTimeout(intervalId) {
        $momentum.worker.postMessage({
          type: 'clearInterval',
          id: intervalId
        });

        delete $momentum.idToCallback[intervalId];
      }

      $momentum.worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        if (e.data.type === 'fire') {
          $momentum.idToCallback[e.data.id]();
        }
      };

      window.$momentum = $momentum;

      window.setInterval = patchedSetInterval;
      window.clearInterval = patchedClearInterval;
      window.setTimeout = patchedSetTimeout;
      window.clearTimeout = patchedClearTimeout;
    })();
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```